# Function result as parameter to another function in where

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell.
I would like to ask, how can I do something like this:

```
where b = goo(a) a = foo()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't use parentheses to call functions in Haskell, simply put a space between the function name and its argument. Also, there are no nullary functions in Haskell, a function has to have at least one parameter. Other than that, put your equations one beneath the other (aligned) and it will work.

Comment: The code you posted seems to be meaningless. You should add some informal description about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you wouldn't call a function like a method in OO languages **()** <- this is not a valid call. But anyway, your question is vague and not very descriptive so I am giving you this answer based mainly on assumption. Calling **b** is simply done by:

```
where b = goo a
      a = foo
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
> let b = goo a
|       where goo f = sum . map f
|             a = \x -> x * x
|
> b [1..3]
14
```